# Hive gives SemanticException [Error 10014]: when Running my UDF

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-udf

I have a hive UDF that does a GeoIP lookup.

```
public static Text evaluate(Text inputFieldName, Text option,
        Text databaseFileName) {

    String inputField, fieldOption, dbFileName, result = null;

    inputField = inputFieldName.toString();
    fieldOption = option.toString();
    dbFileName = databaseFileName.toString();
    ExtractData eed = new ExtractData();
    try {
        result = eed.ExtractDB(inputField, fieldOption,
                dbFileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GeoIp2Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new Text(result);

}
```

And then I made a jar out of this and ran the following in the hive Cli

```
add jar /location_of_jar/MyUDF.jar;
add file /user/riyan/GeoIP2-Enterprise.mmdb;
create temporary function samplefunction as 'com.package.name.App';
select samplefunction('172.73.14.54','country_name','/user/riyan/GeoIP2-Enterprise.mmdb') AS result;
```

I'm passing the location of the GeoIP2-Enterprise.mmdb database to the udf. It works fine on my local system. But when i make jar out of it and run it in cli, it gives me an error saying

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments ''/user/riyan/GeoIP2-Enterprise.mmdb'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public static org.apache.hadoop.io.Text com.package.name.App.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)  on object com.package.name.App@1777c0e2 of class com.package.name.App with arguments {172.73.14.54:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, country_name:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, /user/riyan/GeoIP.mmdb:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text} of size 3
```

I also tried to change the parameters from Text to String and that gave me the same exception.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
thanks

**Edit : Adding the below part**

I ran it in hive debug mode and got this

```
 FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments ''./GeoIP2-Enterprise.mmdb'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String com.package.name.App.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)  on object com.package.name.App@ of class com.package.name.App with arguments {172.73.14.54:java.lang.String, countryCode:java.lang.String, ./GeoIP2-Enterprise.mmdb:java.lang.String} of size 3
17/04/18 11:02:30 [main]: ERROR ql.Driver: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments ''./GeoIP2-Enterprise.mmdb'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String com.bankofamerica.gisds.App.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)  on object com.package.name.App@418d85cb of class com.package.name.App with arguments {172.73.14.54:java.lang.String, countryCode:java.lang.String, ./GeoIP2-Enterprise.mmdb:java.lang.String} of size 3
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments ''./GeoIP2-Enterprise.mmdb'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String com.package.name.App.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)  on object com.package.name.App@418d85cb of class com.package.name.App with arguments {172.73.14.54:java.lang.String, countryCode:java.lang.String, ./GeoIP2-Enterprise.mmdb:java.lang.String} of size 3
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory$DefaultExprProcessor.process(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:1184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultRuleDispatcher.dispatch(DefaultRuleDispatcher.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.dispatchAndReturn(DefaultGraphWalker.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.dispatch(DefaultGraphWalker.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.walk(DefaultGraphWalker.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.startWalking(DefaultGraphWalker.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory.genExprNode(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory.genExprNode(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genAllExprNodeDesc(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genExprNodeDesc(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genSelectPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:3771)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genSelectPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:3550)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genPostGroupByBodyPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:8830)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genBodyPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:8785)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:9652)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:9545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genOPTree(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10018)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10029)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:9909)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:223)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:488)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1391)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1203)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:383)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:775)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:693)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:628)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String com.package.name.App.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)  on object com.package.name.App@418d85cb of class com.package.name.App with arguments {172.73.14.54:java.lang.String, countryCode:java.lang.String, ./GeoIP2-Enterprise.mmdb:java.lang.String} of size 3
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF.initializeAndFoldConstants(GenericUDF.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc.newInstance(ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory$DefaultExprProcessor.getXpathOrFuncExprNodeDesc(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:959)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory$DefaultExprProcessor.process(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:1176)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String com.package.name.App.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)  on object com.package.name.App@418d85cb of class com.package.name.App with arguments {172.73.14.54:java.lang.String, countryCode:java.lang.String, ./GeoIP2-Enterprise.mmdb:java.lang.String} of size 3
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:978)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge.evaluate(GenericUDFBridge.java:182)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF.initializeAndFoldConstants(GenericUDF.java:168)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:954)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode.<init>(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/JsonNodeFactory;Ljava/util/Map;)V
        at com.maxmind.db.Decoder.decodeMap(Decoder.java:285)
        at com.maxmind.db.Decoder.decodeByType(Decoder.java:154)
        at com.maxmind.db.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:147)
        at com.maxmind.db.Decoder.decodeMap(Decoder.java:281)
        at com.maxmind.db.Decoder.decodeByType(Decoder.java:154)
        at com.maxmind.db.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:147)
        at com.maxmind.db.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:87)
        at com.maxmind.db.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:132)
        at com.maxmind.db.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:116)
        at com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader.<init>(DatabaseReader.java:35)
        at com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader.<init>(DatabaseReader.java:23)
        at com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader$Builder.build(DatabaseReader.java:129)
        at com.bankofamerica.gisds.ExtractEnterpriseData.ExtractEnterpriseDB(ExtractEnterpriseData.java:27)
        at com.package.name.App.evaluate(App.java:73)
        ... 46 more
```

Comment: did this problem is resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answre, It looks like you are missing some dependencies in your JAR file. how are you compiling your project that contains the UDF?

Probably missing this one in the Hive classpath

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

As work  around, you could try compile it using jar with dependencies (not a good practice for this case) but at least we will know if that is your problem

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

the other option is add this dependency to the Hive classpath and try again

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.1.4

Comment: does it execute your code? depending on the hive version the error could be not very clear, could you try some dummy logic like return one parameter?

Comment: I added a new dummy evaluate function that returns just a one string. its working fine.
the actual evaluate function is running fine on the local machine...its giving me the above error if I'm running on the cluster

Comment: probably you have some errors here ExtractDB, try run it in your cluster using some tables to trigger a mapreduce job and get the logs from there

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason for the failure is due to the below error.

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode.(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/JsonNodeFactory;Ljava/util/Map;)V

Looks like you might be having conflicting version of jars in the classpath.

add -verbose:class jvm option to hs2 before starting it and then see which jar is getting picked up - remove the jar if it is old or not required for the udf.